# Trying to figure out what is adding strange formatting to my code. I thought it was Prettier, but deactivated it and it was still doing it

Tags: formatting, format, square-bracket, automatic-semicolon-insertion

Before save:

```
`['bud_1', 'pm_1', 'apm'].forEach((field) => {
        let user = this.generalData.users.find((i) => i.sage_id == row[field])
        if (user) {
          row[`${field}_name`] = user.initials
        }
      })

      // Mapping company fields together
      ['architect', 'client', 'engineer', 'owner_rep', 'other_company'].forEach(
        (field) => {
          let company = this.generalData.companies.find(
            (i) => i.id == row[field]
          )
          if (company) {
            row[`${field}_name`] = company.company
          }
        }
      )`
```

After save:

```
`;['bud_1', 'pm_1', 'apm']
        .forEach((field) => {
          let user = this.generalData.users.find((i) => i.sage_id == row[field])
          if (user) {
            row[`${field}_name`] = user.initials
          }
        })

        [
          // Mapping company fields together
          ('architect', 'client', 'engineer', 'owner_rep', 'other_company')
        ].forEach((field) => {
          let company = this.generalData.companies.find(
            (i) => i.id == row[field]
          )
          if (company) {
            row[`${field}_name`] = company.company
          }
        }`
```

My current settings:
`{ "editor.tabSize": 2, "editor.detectIndentation": false, "editor.formatOnPaste": true, "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode", "editor.formatOnSave": true, "editor.formatOnType": true, "typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterConstructor": true, "typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingJsxExpressionBraces": true, "typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBrackets": true, "typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyParenthesis": true, "typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingTemplateStringBraces": true, "typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterTypeAssertion": true, "typescript.format.insertSpaceBeforeFunctionParenthesis": true, "typescript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForControlBlocks": true, "typescript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions": true, "css.format.spaceAroundSelectorSeparator": true, "less.format.spaceAroundSelectorSeparator": true, "javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterConstructor": true, "javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingJsxExpressionBraces": true, "javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingTemplateStringBraces": true, "javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingEmptyBraces": false, "javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBraces": false, "html.format.indentInnerHtml": true, "html.format.indentHandlebars": true, "prettier.printWidth": 90, "prettier.semi": false }`

I am not sure what is auto formatting to add semicolons and also putting the comments in the square brackets.  Any advice would be helpful, thanks!